# How to activate and deactivate certain events? need help please.

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to make a quizz. I am just starting to get into actionscript 3.0 so                                                     please any help would be appreciated.

So basically i am trying to make the four of the buttons that i have either activate or
deactivate their event listeners, i have tried "removeEventListener" and if statements            however i cannot make it work. Please help me out, thanks.

```
/////////navigation for t,o,y and a////////////////////////////////

a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotosomething1);
function gotosomething1 (event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(89);
} 

yy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotosomething2);
function gotosomething2 (event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(89);
} 

t.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotosomething3);
function gotosomething3 (event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(89);
} 

o.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotosomething4);
function gotosomething4 (event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(89);
} 

/////me trying to use the if statement for removing event listener on "a"////////

if(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotosomething2) && (MouseEvent.CLICK, gotosomething3) &&         (MouseEvent.CLICK, gotosomething4)
{
a.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotosomething1);
}
////////////////////end//////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: What the if statement mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deactivate button a after button a is clicked, you would do this:

```
a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotosomething1);
function gotosomething1 (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(89);
    a.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotosomething1);
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to activate button a after buttons yy, t and o have been clicked, you would need to keep track of their statuses using some extra variables.

```
var yyClicked:Boolean = false;
var tClicked:Boolean = false;
var oClicked:Boolean = false;

yy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotosomething2);
function gotosomething2 (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(89);
    yyClicked = true;
    activateA();
} 

t.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotosomething3);
function gotosomething3 (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(89);
    tClicked = true;
    activateA();
} 

o.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotosomething4);
function gotosomething4 (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(89);
    oClicked = true;
    activateA();
} 

function activateA()
{
    if(yyClicked && tClicked && oClicked) 
    {
        a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotosomething1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for the reply it has helped a lot, however i want to "activate" button a after buttons yy, t and o buttons have been clicked. In order to do that do i just change the "a.removeEventListener" function? And thankyou again for the help.

Comment: @user2521634 I have updated the answer in response to your question.